Graphics Artifacting with dell XPS 16
I just picked up a dell XPS 16 laptop (cool thing) and wanted to put Ubuntu on it. So I downloaded LTS (24.04-desktop-amd64.iso) and went through install. The installer worked fine and I could even run a basic WebGL animation to test the graphics card in firefox while I waited (was bored). After installing ubuntu as you would normally and booting into it, the screen started acting all weird, as you can see here. For context I'd like to state that this is from neofetch:

CPU: Intel Ultra 9 185H (22) @ 4.800GHz
GPU: Intel Arc Graphics]
NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Max-Q / Mobile

I did some tests and couldn't get any to work, including reinstalling Ubuntu in "safe graphics" mode. Does anyone have any ideas or things I can try? I'd like to still utilize my graphics card(s). Thank you very much.
Edit 1, Graphics info from System Details tab:
Graphics: Intel Arc Graphics (MTL)
Graphics 1: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 4060 Laptop GPU

Go to Settings, System, System Details copy your Graphics info and edit your question with the info, do not put the info  in remarks.

Details added! Hope this helps, thank you for your response!

Same issue with a new XPS 13 (Intel Ultra 155H) with Arc iGPU). Exact same artifacts whenever I move the mouse with a fresh Ubuntu 24.04. Any luck? Not sure if I should return the notebook within my 2 weeks. Dell support says they are unsure if they will support Ubuntu 24

Using an external monitor fixes the issue, so maybe my issue is not related to the iGPU, my bad.

Short update: horizontal lines on non touch internal display only appear on kernel 6.8.0-40 but not on 6.8.0-36, if anybody has this issue, too :)

I had the same issue Dell XPS 14 9440
Tried to go back to kernel 6.8.0-36 without success.
Tried 6.8.0-45 and it fixed my issue
Install new kernel if you don't have it already
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-image-6.8.0-45-generic

Set as default
sudo vim /etc/default/grub

GRUB_DEFAULT="Advanced options for Ubuntu>Ubuntu, with Linux 6.8.0-45-generic"

Update grub
sudo update-grub

Reboot
sudo reboot

Verify
cat /proc/version

Linux version 6.5.0-45-generic

6.8.0-45 isn't even available on my Ubuntu 24.04 machine, just -44.

The solution is to disable power saving feature:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/2062951/comments/70
"i915.enable_psr2_sel_fetch=0"
If no kernel option works.

I have solved my issue, I hope someone else can benefit from this!
Edit a grub file:
sudo nano /etc/default/grub

I made my line have "nomodeset" in addition to "quiet splash".
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"

This solved the issue!

Bad move. You just stopped the OS from using the installed video driver.  nomodeset is a temporary fix, added to your Grub menu, to get past a black screen. After using it, you need to install the correct graphics driver. When you reboot, it is not necessary and will disappear

@David My issue is that I set the drivers to nvidia 555 but it seems like that doesn't solve it. The only thing that I can fix the artifcacting with is the nomodeset. At this point I don't know if there's even support for XPS 16 from canonical yet so that's why I'm going with this for now. If anyone knows something else, please let me know!

Noting to do with Canonical it is up to Nvidia to make the driver. Have you chacked their web site as to what support they off for the card?
